# ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION optimization

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, query-performance

I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Price ASC) as RowNum
    from Offers) r
where RowNum = 1
```

Offers table contains about 10 million records. But there are only ~4000 distinct codes there. So I need to get the row with the lowest price for each code and there will be only 4000 rows in the result.

I have an Index on (Code, Price) columns with all other columns in INCLUDE statement.

The query runs for 2 minutes. And if I look at the execution plan, I see Index scan with 10M actual rows. So, I guess it scans the whole index to get needed values.

Why MSSQL do the whole index scan? Is it because subquery needs the whole data? How to avoid this scan? Is there a SQL hint to process only the first row in partition?

Is there another way to optimize such query?

Comment: Does the subquery by itself include a table scan?

Comment: @AaronDietz yes, it does. It needs to set the rank for each row and it seems logical. Maybe I want MSSQL optimizer do all things and it's the answer to 'Why MSSQL do the whole index scan?' question.

Comment: It seem off that would take 2 minutes.  I would look for other stuff going on.  Try with  nolock - often not a good solution but will indicate if locks are the problem.   Defrag the index.

Comment: @Paparazzi I've tried WITH (NOLOCK) and OPTION(RECOMPILE) and it didn't help

Comment: What fields do you need from the offers table.? Why not do a group by query on code and price and join back onto the offers table on code and price

Comment: @Andrew currently, the table has multiple records with the same price for a code. And it doen't matter for business which one I take from the group. If it does matter, I can always add a new condition (new field) with the current approach. Anyway it takes more time to join 10M record table to itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After trying multiple different solutions, I've found the fastest query with CROSS APPLY statement:

```
SELECT C.* 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Code from Offers) A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM Offers B
             WHERE A.Code  = B.Code 
             ORDER by Price) C
```

It take ~1 second to run.

Comment: In your case you needed the top 1 row, in my case I needed the top 8... so I needed an OUTER JOIN instead of CROSS APPLY.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating an index on `( Code, Price )` without including the other columns and then (assuming that there is a unique `Id` column):

```
select L.*
  from Offers as L inner join
  ( select Id,
      Row_Number() over ( partition by Code order by Price ) as RN
    from Offers ) as R on R.Id = L.Id and R.RN = 1
```

An index scan on a smaller index ought to help.

Second guess would be to get the `Id` of the row with the lowest `Price` for each `Code` explicitly: Get `distinct Code` values, get `Id` of `top 1` (to avoid problems with duplicate prices) `Min( Price )` row for that `Code`, join with `Offers` to get complete rows. Again, the more compact index should help.

Comment: The first solution is much slower. What do you mean by your second guess? The problem is to get Id of record with minimal price in group. I tried to achieve this using partition and rownumber, but it's slow.

Comment: The idea is to _encourage_ the query optimizer to use an index in an optimal way. If it does a seek on a `Code` value into an index on `( Code, Price )` the first match will also provide the minimum value for `Price`. It can then access the full row and return the required data. Does an index without included columns improve the performance of your original query? (Check the execution plan to see if the index is being used.) Another approach would involve using triggers to maintain a table of unique `Code` values to avoid the overhead of `distinct`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you'll get any significant performance gains, but you may want to try the **WITH TIES** clause

**Example**

```
Select Top 1 with Ties *
 From  Offers
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By Code Order By Price)
```